# Contar palabras repetidas de una columna en javascript o jquery

Tags: javascript, tablas

tengo una tabla en la cual existe una columna que tiene algunos datos específicos, algunos datos se repiten, por ejemplo:

```
"columna_1||columna_2"            
"Nombre 1 ||Técnico en sistemas"     
"Nombre 2 ||Técnico en sistemas"   
"Nombre 3 ||Otra carrera"         
"Nombre 4 ||Otra carrera"                                                               
"Nombre 5 ||Otra carrera"
```

Necesito agrupar los datos de la columna 2 y que el resultado sea:
Técnico en sistemas 2 items.
Otra carrera 3 items.

Agradezco toda la ayuda posible.
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Por si alguien lo necesita comparto la solución

```
//obtengo los datos de la columna
var rows = $(".name_line");
//creo un array el cual guardare los datos para después comparar
var arr = {};
//recorro los campos de la columna
rows.each(function(){
  //obtengo el texto del campo correspondiente
  var val = $(this).text();
  //realizo las comparaciones y realiza el conteo
  if (val === "") return;
  if (typeof(arr[val])!= "undefined"){
      arr[val] = ++arr[val];
  }
  else{
      arr[val] = 1;
  }
});
//mostramos los datos en consola
 console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Con un bucle anidado en otro comparas los valores con una condición, si la condicion es true contador++.

```
    var contador = new Array();
    var temporal;
    for(var i=0; i< columna2.length;i++){
        temporal = columna2[i];
        for(var a=0; a< columna2.length;a++){
            if(temporal[i]===columna2[a]){
                contador[i]++; 
             }
        }
     }
```

en este caso contador[0] seria igual a 0, contador[1] a 2, y contador[2] a 3

Comment: Su código solo hace un conteo de columnas, no era lo que buscaba, al final lo conseguí usando otro método, aun así muchas gracias por la ayuda.